# What is the hardness and hit points of a magical +2 rapier?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

Pathfinder system, enchanted rapier with +2 enhancement. What is the hardness and hit points of the sword?

Comment: Just curious, why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably due to the ease of finding an answer, I suspect. Shows lack of research, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weapon Hardness and Hit Points can be found in a table [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/). From the table, a rapier is a one-handed blade, and not light. Therefore, it starts with a base hardness of 10 and 5hp. Magic Weapons, from note 1 and 3 on the table, add +2 and +10 per bonus, giving totals of 14 hardness and 25hp.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn’t have thought to search there.